# Difference between dot and greater-than sign in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the difference between `key.other_key` and `key>other_key` in Elasticsearch? I've come across it in [this page in docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and can't find a further explanation of why it's needed and how it's different from a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These symbols are used together when a [`buckets_path` syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#buckets-path-syntax) is used:

```
AGG_SEPARATOR       =  '>' ;
METRIC_SEPARATOR    =  '.' ;
AGG_NAME            =  <the name of the aggregation> ;
METRIC              =  <the name of the metric (in case of multi-value metrics aggregation)> ;
PATH                =  <AGG_NAME> [ <AGG_SEPARATOR>, <AGG_NAME> ]* [ <METRIC_SEPARATOR>, <METRIC> ] ;
```

You need this when using [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) or when sorting buckets of `terms` aggregation.

The difference in semantics is best shown with the example from the [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) you referenced in the question:

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "countries" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "artist.country",
                "order" : { "rock>playback_stats.avg" : "desc" }
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "rock" : {
                    "filter" : { "term" : { "genre" :  "rock" }},
                    "aggs" : {
                        "playback_stats" : { "stats" : { "field" : "play_count" }}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The above will sort the artist’s countries buckets based on the average play count among the rock songs.

Here `>` symbol is used to separate different levels of the aggregations (`playback_stats` is a sub-aggregation of `rock`), and the dot indicates which metric of the aggregation to use for sorting, in this case `avg`.

Hope that helps!